# Adding a frame around fragments in a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments

I understand that in order to swipe between activities I need to use the `FragmentPageAdapter` as in the answer to this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775757/android-swiping-between-activities) question.

However, I'm trying to put a frame around the `Fragments` that does not move. Something like a picture frame that stays in place around the edges of the screen and when you swipe, the frame stays in place, while the `Fragments` slide between each other. Basically, a masking effect. How can I implement this?

In my FragmentActivity's FragmentPagerAdapter I have a different Fragment that I call compared to the example shown which is a list fragment (ArrayListFragment). I use a a generic fragment as so:

```
public static class TestFragment extends Fragment{
        /**
         * Create a new instance of DetailsFragment, initialized to
         * show the text at 'index'.
         */
        public static TestFragment newInstance(int index) {
            TestFragment f = new TestFragment();

            // Supply index input as an argument.
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("index", index);
            f.setArguments(args);

            return f;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mytext, container, false);
            return v;
        }
    }
```

The mytext layout is quite simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:text="woohoo"
        android:gravity="center"></TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way to implement that frame is to put the `ViewPager` in a `FrameLayout` or a `RelativeLayout` with a custom `View` on top of it:

```
<FrameLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.luksprog.ViewPagerOverlayFrame
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

In that custom `View`'s `onDraw` method you'll draw the frame you want. The code below will draw a unswipeable red frame near the edges of the `ViewPager`:

```
public class ViewPagerOverlayFrame extends View {

    private Paint mPaint;   

    public ViewPagerOverlayFrame(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED); 
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(60.0f);       
    }

    public ViewPagerOverlayFrame(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(60.0f);       
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawLine(0, 0, getMeasuredWidth(), 0, mPaint);
        canvas.drawLine(getMeasuredWidth(), 0, getMeasuredWidth(),
                getMeasuredHeight(), mPaint);
        canvas.drawLine(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight(), 0,
                getMeasuredHeight(), mPaint);
        canvas.drawLine(0, getMeasuredHeight(), 0, 0, mPaint);
    }

}
```

You may want to add some padding to the `ViewPager` so its content doesn't get clipped by the frame.

Comment: Hm, this seems to hide the content in my underlying fragment. Also, is there away to use a custom image (.PNG) format? like [this](http://www.juadgallery.com/images/v-frame.png) Would I need to create a custom ImageView?

Comment: @codedawg82 Yes my code "hides" the content below(that is way I recommended setting padding on the `ViewPager`). You can't draw a `png` directly on the `canvas` but you can use the `BitmapFactory` class to transform it in a `Bitmap` and then use it. I would break the `png` in 4 pieces, top, left, right, bottom.

Comment: Adding padding in the ViewPager element did not work. I've added my fragment code above -- maybe this has something to do with the problem? Adding a TextView element directly before the custom overlay you showed, properly shows up. However, when the textview is placed in the fragment layout it doesn't (even with padding).

Comment: @codedawg82 I don't see how setting padding on the `ViewPager` didn't worked as I've done this in several cases with the right results. Try to add the padding to the root of the `fragment`'s layout.

Comment: In the LinearLayout I use in the fragment's layout, I added "android:padding="50dp" and this worked properly, but adding this to the ViewPager element you have above did not. I don't know why exactly, but my problem is solved.